# Does Azure provide “Serverless” options for WebSocket connections to API?

Tags: azure, websocket, serverless

I am trying to learn Azure Functions by creating a bot that checks the stock prices. Ticker prices should be obtained using the BitMex API over a websocket.

Since Azure Functions currently do not directly support websockets, what implementation would you suggest I use?

There are many SignalR examples , but they all involve your own code forwarding data to SignalR in some way. I need SignalR (or whatever solution) to get the data from a foreign server via API.

The solution must preferably be serverless.